# Format databars rules using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Currently I am trying to set databar color to red using Interop Excel in C# when export to xlsx file but I don't know the correct way of accessing the properties (E.g. bar color, direction) listed in the microsoft docs as there are no examples. Does anyone know how? Below is my code.

```
Excel.Range range1 = excelWorkSheet.Range["H4", "V4"];     
range1.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();
```

Comment: [AddDatabar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.formatconditions.adddatabar?view=excel-pia) is a *function*, it returns an object of type DataBar.  So write `DataBar bar = (DataBar)range1.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();` and set properties like BarColor and Direction.

Comment: thank you :) it worked.using Databar bar = range1.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();